# Cross conduction in class-B power amplifier

Tags: mosfet-driver, class-b-amplifier

can someone explain me why in this class-B power amplifier circuit, those two signal(driver?) mosfet generate a lot of cross condution ?

the two mosfet i used :  [2N7002](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BSS84.pdf) and [BSS84](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds11303.pdf)

[image: Circuit]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Who said that is a class-B amplifier?

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFETs don't immediately switch, and they won't both switch at exactly the same time. There is a period when both are 'on' and as such you get shoot through.

You need to drive the gates independently with some dead time to eliminate it.